# get a sql server 2000 database out of emergency mode

Tags: database, sql-server

there is a db in emergency mode,which i was told to make it "normal". in the enterprise manager i can not see any objects(like tables, users and stuff). in the guy's computer, i connect to the server via toad, and copied all the tables and users and functions etc.

`dbcc checkdb` returned 0 errors. and after getting all the data i can get, i typed `alter database 'name' set online` . which changed nothing, the db was still in emergency mode.

i am not familiar with all those db modes, so i appreciate aany help i can get.

right now, db properties show that its in multi user mode, and still in emergency

Thanks

Comment: Start looking for a recent backup of the database

Comment: problem about the backup is that there isn't any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short form is you are hosed, because in SQL Server 2000 there's no documented, official way to bring a database out of emergency mode. In the past, I've just had to restore the database from a backup. This is why a good recovery plan is necessary (including regular testing of backups, so you don't get stuck with a bad backup file). The steps are complicated to try to recover; you should take a look at this article: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/checkdb-from-every-angle-emergency-mode-repair-the-very-very-last-resort.aspx

Comment: problem is, noone at that end have any backups of the db. so restore is not an option. i did create another db with all the data i can get, and changed their web application's connection string. it looks like its running. ty for the reply and the link, looks really helpful.